# How to store a list of different generic things in C#

Tags: c#, generics, collections

Say for example I have this base class

```
class Mangler<TInput, TOutput>
{
}
```

And then I make a couple of derived classes

```
class StringToBytesMangler : Mangler<string, byte[]>
{
}

class IntToGuidMangler : Mangler<int, Guid>
{
}
```

How do I store a collection of `Mangler<TInput, TOutput>` where `TInput` and `TOutput` may be different at any given time?

i.e.

```
List<Mangler<?, ?>> list = new List<Mangler<?, ?>>();

list.Add(new StringToBytesMangler());
list.Add(new IntToGuidMangler());
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `Mangler<string,byte[]>` and `Mangler<int,Guid>` are completely different types, so the only generic list to keep them could be a `List<object>`. Maybe you can derive `Mangler<TInput,TOutput>` from another base class or interface and use that type for the list.

Comment: Check [Covariance and Contravariance](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq/).

Comment: @AlexB. Good comment, although `string` and `int` and `byte[]` and `Guid` are somewhat unrelated types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, this is not possible the way you tried it. The types `StringToBytesMangler` and `IntToGuidMangler` do *not* derive from the same type. You could introduce a shared base type, but I recommend reconsidering the design - even if they could be stored in the same collection, they would syntactically have nothing in common (at least it isn't shown in the question).

Answer (score 3):

You need a non-generic `Mangler` base class.

```
List<Mangler> list = new List<Mangler>();

list.Add(new StringToBytesMangler());
list.Add(new IntToGuidMangler());
```

Of course, this means you also need to have non-generic versions of the methods that depend on `TInput` or `TOutput`.

Comment: Or an `object`.

Comment: @Sinatr, yes, but that's ugly, and it doesn't let you define methods that expose the class functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea behind generics is to have generic code so type of that class can be treated the same. From what you have posted, it is not easy to see what generic code you have.

Below I have a class that has some generic code:

```
class Mangler<TInput, TOutput> 
   where TInput: ITInput 
   where TOutput: ITOutput {

   public TInput Input { get; set; }
   public TOutput Output { get; set; }
   public bool IsInputAGuid() {
      if (Guid.Parse(this.Input.SomeThing) == this.Output.SomeGuid ) {
         return true;
      }

      return false;
   }
}
```

You can see in the above class, when it parses a string to a `Guid` from `this.Input.Something` and then it performs `==` on it with `this.Ouput.SomeGuid`, the compiler is happy because we have made the constraint that `TInput` must implement the interface `ITInput` so the compiler knows this line will work and `Input` will have `Something` as a `string` property:

```
Guid.Parse(this.Input.SomeThing)
```

The compiler does not care what the concrete type is so long as `Something` is available. It is the same idea for `TOuput` but the compiler expects that it implements `ITOutput` so it expects a `Guid` in `SomeGuid`. This is why the compiler is happy to parse a string to a guid and then perform the `==` operator on it with another thing which is also a `Guid`.

Here are the interfaces and some classes which implement them:

```
internal interface ITInput {
   string SomeThing { get; set; }
}

internal interface ITOutput {
   Guid SomeGuid { get; set; }
}

internal class AnotherInput : ITInput {
   public string SomeThing { get; set; }
}

internal class SomeInput : ITInput {
   public string SomeThing { get; set; }
}

internal class SomeOutput : ITOutput {
   public Guid SomeGuid { get; set; }
}

internal class SomeOtherOutput : ITOutput {
   public Guid SomeGuid { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, here is the usage where we can treat these generically:

```
var manglers = new List<Mangler<ITInput, ITOutput>>();

manglers.Add( new Mangler<ITInput, ITOutput>
{ Input = new SomeInput(), Output = new SomeOutput()  } );

manglers.Add( new Mangler<ITInput, ITOutput>
{ Input = new AnotherInput(), Output = new SomeOutput() } );

foreach( var thisMangler in manglers ) {
   var input = thisMangler.Input;
   var output = thisMangler.Output;
   var success = thisMangler.IsInputAGuid();
}
```

You can see in the `foreach` regardless of the concrete type, we can call `Input`, `Output` and `IsInputAGuid()` on all of them.

So in your code find what code is generic and then apply the above technique to it. You can either use interfaces or a base class for your constraints.

Comment: So the whole idea is to use interface. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: An interface or a base class which has code that is common so you can treat the objects the same because they share a common interface.